# Android: corrupted TextView using .setShader()

Tags: android, shader, textview

I'm trying to create an old-style 8bit effect on some Android text views, using the following code:

```
 private static Shader InversetextShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 22,
                                          new int[] { Color.RED, Color.BLUE },
                                          new float[] { 0, 1 }, TileMode.CLAMP);

 TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t1.setText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name_mele));
    t1.getPaint().setShader(InversetextShader);
    t1.setTypeface(font);
    t1.setShadowLayer(4f, 2.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
```

The code is working on Android < 3, but is giving me problem since when I began to target ICS (API Level 14).

The TextView are pretty simple:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRecords1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>
```

This is an image showing the defect, some black lines that should't be there:

( I'm sorry I can't post images )

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRWOM.png

If I shut display OFF (i.e. locking the phone) and then ON again, the defect goes away. I alread tried calling .invalidate() and drawing Views again, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug in the UI toolkit OpenGL renderer. On what version of ICS does this occur exactly? Do you have an APK I could use to reproduce the problem and possibly fix it if it still exists? **As a workaround**, you can use

```
yourLayout.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,yourLayout.getPaint);
```

on your TextViews to force software rendering.

Comment: the workaround is working, thank you!!



I got the error only on my nexus S at version 4.0.4. Emulator is working.

APK is here: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.icecuber.amazza)